# What is the maximum sampling rate for GPS on Android

Tags: android, gps, rate

The maximum sampling rate for GPS I can achieve on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) is 1Hz with the following setting:

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Is it possible to boost it towards 10Hz? Is it limited by hardware or Android software? I know that GPS chips can go up to 10Hz.

Similar question was asked here. However, it was 3 years ago (maybe the situation has changed):
[getting the highest GPS update rate from the GPS Hardware in my Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17827142/6871559)

Comment: Have you manage to figure this out? 1Hz is really not enough for logging purposes, e.g. in motorsports.

Comment: No, was not able to push it higher :(

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the usual accuracy of GPS positioning can be between 4 - 7 meters.

With this dispersion in the localization rather than having many measures what is interesting is to have good algorithms for example to calculate the distance traveled.

Answer (score -1):

Garmin GLO GPS/GLONASS rate is 10Hz max (depending on hosting environment).  This device is bluetooth only;  has no display. You should pay $100 max.

https://www.gpscompared.net/garmin-glo-portable-gps-and-glonass-receiver